# Duplicate resource id for xml views

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am facing a weird issue. I am setting ids to XML views. When I try to reference the id in my activity or fragment I am getting a double reference to it. Please find the screenshot :

[image]

It is referencing the same view. And because of this none of my changes in the XML file are reflecting on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so try clean project **Invalidate cache and Restart Project** in Android Studio.

Comment: I have done it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Invalidate caches/restart, and also try clean project and rebuild project.

Comment: Done, Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

1st
close android studio, Delete your project .idea and .gradle files and again reload android studio.
OR
2nd
Delete catches of android studio from C: folder

Comment: Can you please tell me which folder should be deleted from the C drive?

Comment: Which catches file are you saying? I cannot find any.

Comment: I mean delete C:\USERPROFILE\.gradle\caches and reload android studio.hope might this help.